# CSS circle Spin/Grow transition, text starting outside

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a circle that I want to grow both width and height and spin to face upright. The problem is you can see the embedded checkmark starts outside of the circle and spirals inwards as opposed to growing with the circle.

```js
$(function() {
 $("span").addClass("active");
})
```

```css
span {
 position: absolute;
 display:block;
 color: red;
 font-size: 0px;
 font-weight: bold;
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform:  translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
 line-height:80px;
 text-align: center;
 background: rgba(32,167,110,0.9);
 border: 2px solid rgb(32,167,110);
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
 -ms-transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
 transform: rotateZ(-360sdeg);
 transition: all 5s;
 margin-left: -20px;
 margin-top:-34px;
}

span.active {
 -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
 -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
 transform: rotateZ(0sdeg);
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 font-size: 45px;
 margin-left: -40px;
 margin-top:-68px;
}
```

```html
<span>✓</span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I would like to keep the checkmark centered inside the circle as it grows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got your question correctly, but if you want to hide the checkmark outside of the green circle you can add the css property `overflow: hidden;`.

**EDIT**: According to the author's comment, I added a new solution.

If you want to position the checkmark sign inside the circle and nevertheless transform it together with the circle, it is best to add another element (or pseudoelement) for the checkmark sign and only assign the transformation to the circle. Here is an example of the transformation with a pseudoelement.

```js
$(function() {
    $("span").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
/* <div> is only for layouting (centering into the middle) */
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

span {
    display: block;
    position: relative; /* needs to be set, that the checkmark is positioned relative to the <span> */
    color: red;
    font-size: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(32,167,110,0.9);
    border: 2px solid rgb(32,167,110);
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transition: all 5s;
}

span:after {
    content: "✓";
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

span.active {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span></span>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah sorry I guess I didn't finish my question, I would like to try to keep the check centered and grow with the circle. This may be a good backup if I can't though, thanks.

Comment: Okay, but the checkmark should rotate in the center of growing circle?

Comment: Both should rotate. The whole thing should look like one solid piece, both rotating and growing. With the check mark in the center.

Comment: Perfect!! Also makes the code that generates this circle cleaner! Thank you.